# PHP - Check to see if an image has a drop shadow added?

Tags: php, image, dropshadow

I'm wondering if there's a decent way or any of some sort to check an image to see if there is a drop shadow added.  Doing this with php, if possible.

Just curious if there's any clever way of going about this, possibly.

Thanks,
Shawn

Comment: I will be very interested in knowing how as well..

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no "clever" way of doing this if you mean a drop shadow inside the image. You need to do it the hard way with gd or imagemagick or something like that. Manually testing for gradients.

If you mean an html border, you can of course check the css of the element.